# R Subset "[..]" wrong values

Tags: r, subset

I am pretty selftought in R so I dont have that much expertise.
But when I recently checked some "tripple"-subsetted data, I recognized some errors which I cant explain, even after several expereminental attempts.

```
> data <- read.csv("MEC7 table_R.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
> show(data)
   Accession Nitrogen.supply Replicate chlorophylle.A chlorophylle.B carotenoids  phenols flavanoids carbohydrates   proteins
1      HM022             Fix         2       35.71822       13.61773    5.328781 349.0419  116.20386      108.6696   4.602691
2      HM022             Fix         4       72.79944       26.31981   12.419295 324.1432         NA      113.3090  10.127329
3      HM022             Fed         3       40.84556       14.78139    7.844996 424.2241  118.89316      149.3712   8.624055
4      HM022             Fed         4       51.43829       18.34177   10.417405 428.2580         NA      120.8249  71.665152
5      HM022             Fix         3       55.42231       18.73236    5.644060 210.9737  104.85056      391.5803   6.043350
6      HM022             Fed         2       55.77691       18.66710    7.606938 359.6686  117.05009      271.1971   7.368690
7      HM306             Fed         3       51.23863       20.18586    8.830432 444.5283  158.76851      324.4583   2.757425
8      HM306             Fix         4       90.45100       31.74905   14.505800 388.7416  113.75900      250.3901  16.132638
9      HM022             Fix         1       66.61150       22.31275   11.134300 328.1411  152.92800      387.9007   7.821263
10     HM022             Fed         1       67.63950       21.24895   12.076750 483.3238  130.51800      273.0234   6.382024
11     HM306             Fed         2       65.51469       22.45891   13.603800       NA         NA            NA         NA
12     HM306             Fix         2      117.65653       37.67211   20.725213       NA         NA            NA         NA
13     HM306             Fix         3      100.54241       34.42628   20.371192       NA         NA     1273.3765 244.340559
14     HM306             Fed         1       58.26609       22.47596   10.582551 317.4561   99.01719      319.1538   5.822906
15     HM306             Fed         1       66.12246       22.63671   13.222049 399.5537   96.86456      437.4982   4.082517
16     HM306             Fed         4       84.31291       29.05635   17.092142 411.3784   75.22140      387.2773   5.593258
> Chla <- data$chlorophylle.A
> Chla022 <- Chla[data$Accession=="HM022"]
> Chla022Fix <- Chla022[data$Nitrogen.supply=="Fix"]
> Chla022Fix
[1] 35.71822 72.79944 55.42231 67.63950       NA       NA       NA
```

As u can see the value of line 9 ("Fix") was confused with that from line 10 ("Fed") and similar errors appear in other columns as well (chlb, carotenoids etc.). Also the NA values are not clear to me.
Do I miss something? This is very disturbing for me.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Accession=="HM022" & Nitrogen.supply=="Fix") %>%
  pull(chlorophylle.A)

[1] 35.71822 72.79944 55.42231 66.61150
```

And in base R you can do following solution. Here `[[`() is an equivalent to `function(x) x[["chlorophylle.A"]]` , in case you would like to extract `chlorophylle.A` column of your data frame.

```
`[[`(subset(df, Accession=="HM022" & Nitrogen.supply=="Fix"), "chlorophylle.A")

[1] 35.71822 72.79944 55.42231 66.61150
```

Or in case you wanted to stick by your own code. First keep in mind that we subset our data set by rows where variables `Accession` and `Nitrogen.supply` meet our requirements. After that we extract our desired column which is `chlorophylle.A`:

```
df <- df[df$Accession == "HM022" & df$Nitrogen.supply == "Fix", ] 
df <- df$chlorophylle.A

[1] 35.71822 72.79944 55.42231 66.61150
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the input! I will look into this! 
So i guess my main mistake was to pick the column and then the rows.
And yes, the result u got is what i wanted ;)

Comment: There was actually not a mistake. In your last line of code `Chla022[data$Nitrogen.supply=="Fix"]` the length of the expression in the bracket is longer that `Chla022` which is actually 4 here. Whereas `data$Nitrogen.supply=="Fix"` has 7 elements so that's why there are 3 `NA` values in your output. You can run every piece of your code and verify that. You're welcome @marfin1990